# Tracing undefined reference

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ld

How can I trace an undefined reference with `gcc ld`?

I have tried `-Wl`,`-trace-symbol=some_ref` but it does not show from where the symbol is being invoked. I want to get some kind of call stack that shows why the symbol is being invoked in the first place. So in short, I need to trace all references of that symbol from top level down.

Is there a flag for this?

Comment: What is your real problem? If I have a undefined reference I get a info with source line included like this: `main.cpp:5: undefined reference to _example`

Comment: A source issuing an `undefined reference` cannot be compiled, so there is nothing to "trace". Unless you literally mean, tracing where *gcc* issues the error? (Which sounds like an outrageous solution.) A simple text find in your source near the issued error line ought to be enough.

Comment: http://devpit.org/wiki/GCC .. might that help?

Comment: Whether it's actually invoked doesn't matter, it only needs to be referred to by name somewhere (even in "dead" code) for a definition to be necessary.

Comment: The problem is the undefined reference is _sbrk in newlib. I should not be getting undefined reference to this syscall because I'm not using any dynamic allocations (everything linked fine before). So I want to trace the reference and see the full path to this call from my application (ie what code is causing it to be included into the final image).

Comment: Yes, I want to find where it is referenced from. Regardless of whether it's dead code or not, I need to get rid of the code that is calling it because dynamic allocation currently should not be used.

Comment: Probably somewhere in a library that you are now calling, but didn't before. Neither the C standard library, nor STL give any guarantees on calling `malloc` or `new`.  One (obscure) case I know of is, `printf` with floating point formats allocate memory. You could build your own `_sbrk` and put a breakpoint or illegal instruction, if you think it will happen [rather than for example you never call `printf` with float format, but if you were to, it would fail]

Answer (score 2):

Because the question is unclear for me and only the comments give me an idea I try to give you some hints:

As I understand you get a undefined reference from a library so I try to reproduce a example:

lib functions with undefined f1();

```
void f2();
int main()
{
    f2();
}
```

main, calls f2() which calls undefined f1()

void f2();

```
int main() 
{
    f2();
}
int dummy(){}
```

Compile/link with:

```
gcc lib.c -g -c
gcc main.c -g -c
gcc main.o lib.o
```

Results also in a message with source of problem:

```
lib.o: In function `f2':   
lib.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `f1()'
```

If you now want to know where f2 is called from, to get an idea where is the start point of the call tree try:

```
objdump -x <files which potentially call f2()> | grep f2
```

This results in

```
objdump -x main.o | grep f2
0000000000000000            *UND*  0000000000000000 f2
000000000000000a R_X86_64_PC32     f2-0x0000000000000004
```

Here you can see that the symbol was referenced at offset 0xa.

Find out which function is there:

```
objdump -d main.o

0000000000000000 <main>:
0:   55                      push   %rbp
1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
4:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <main+0xe>
e:   5d                      pop    %rbp
f:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000010 <dummy>:
10:   55                      push   %rbp
11:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
14:   5d                      pop    %rbp
15:   c3                      retq
```

As result offset 0x0a is in function `main()`.

Much simpler this can be done by invoking gdb with the found object file:

```
 gdb main.o
 gdb> l *0x0a
 0xa is in main (main.c:5)
```

If you have no debug info: recompile with debug info :-) If you have no debug info in your library check if you can the debug symbols as external file. Howto: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html